# Returning a boolean instead of succeed fail in protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webdriver, protractor

What I am trying to do is identify if a logged in user is a customer of a company.  I have a div that will show the manger id if the person logging in is a manger and redirect to the login screen if they are not.  I want to conditionally test if the account id that is trying to login is a customer or manger and do different things if one or the other is the case.  If the test resolves as true, everything is fine and the promise is resolved but if it fails, the test just stalls (waits for an answer until the wait has run its course) instead of giving a false result.

```
.then(browser.executeScript('return window.find("isCompany:true");')), 
.then(function () {
        return expect(browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.id("url")), qr), wait)).toBe(true);
    }, function () {
          ....
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to resolve the promises returned by `browser.wait()`:

```
browser.wait(EC.textToBePresentInElement(element(by.id("isCompany")), 'true'), wait).then(function () {
    // user is a customer
}, function () {
    // user is not a customer
});
```

Comment: Nope, the result is essentially the same issue, if the test resolves as true, everything is fine and the promise is true but if it fails, the test just stalls (waits for a true answer until the wait has run its course) instead of giving a false result.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easier if you setup a helper function to return the value of `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement`. Then you don't have to worry about chaining the promises together. I use a helper class called `Utils` to accomplish pretty much the same thing as what you are doing. Here's an example

In the utils class I have:

```
function waitForElementText(element, elementText) {
    return browser.wait(this.ec.textToBePresentInElement(element, elementText), this.timeout);
}
```

Using your code snippet you would use it like this:

```
util.waitForElementText(element, elementText)
    .then(function (isCompany) {
        if(isCompany) {
           // do something
        } else {
           // do something else
        }            
}
```